# Invoking synchronized getter and setter

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I am trying to practice synchronize keyword with methods.

I wrote the following code:

**Adder class:**

```
public class Adder implements Runnable{
    Counter counter;
    Adder(Counter counter){
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
            counter.setCount(counter.getCount()+1);
    }
}
```

Counter class:

```
public class Counter {

    private int count = 0;

    public synchronized void setCount(int val){
        count = val;
    }

    public synchronized int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

**main:**

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        Adder adder = new Adder(counter);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(adder);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(adder);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(counter.getCount());
    }
}
```

I would expect the output of this to be 200, but it's not deterministic (theoretically, can have any value between 0-200). I suspect the problems is that I am using the getter and setter inline, i.e.

```
counter.setCount(counter.getCount()+1);
```

For some reason this "breaks" the mutual exclusion that I am trying to achieve with synchronization, but I can't see why.

I implemented the 1's addition with count++ like so:

```
public synchronized void add1(){
        count++;
}
```

This worked, maybe because this way I use only one function instead of two inline. *Could you explain why the first implementation doesn't work?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the getter and subsequent calling of setter is two independent operations. "Set the result of getter plus one" is not atomic here. So you may perfectly have two gets returning the same value, and two sets of the same value increased by one.

Assume `count` is `100`. You have two threads calls calling the getter, both getting 100. Then they both call the setter, setting 101. So the counter is now 101, not 102 - and both threads "were there" already.

So the result is non-deterministic and depends on the actual order of get/set operations from the two threads.

Comment: Thank you. I think the key to understanding this, is to know how that line of code is executed. I thought set() gets executed first, and therefore the first thread that acquires the lock will hold it until the end of the set operation. Instead the get() gets executed first, so 2 threads can call it subsequently, and therefore hold the same value, which is wrong

Comment: @Elira Well, you need arguments before you can invoke a method this is why getter is called first. If you want to try it the other way round, modify your setter to accept an `IntSupplier` and pass `() -> counter.getCount() + 1`. Then in setter, set `count` to `supplier.getAsInt()`. In this case the setter will get called first - before the getter is called. (Don't forget to declare `count` as `volatile`.)

Answer (score 1):

`counter.setCount(counter.getCount()+1);` **is NOT atomic** and it involves 3 steps:

(1) Read the value of `count`

(2) Add one to `count`

(3) Write the value of `count`

In the first approach, you are getting the locks independently i.e., in between the `get` and `set` calls of one thread there will be an interference of other threads. So you can't guarantee that the first thread read value is the same as when it comes for the writing.

In the second approach, you are holding the lock and performing all of the above 3 steps, so you will not find any problem.

Also, you can also solve your problem by using the threadsafe [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class.

Comment: AtomicInteger turns out to be a very convenient tool. Thank you